# Find the angle with these coplanar forces

Tags: vectors

I wish to solve this problem.

I am unsure where to begin. The vertical force of 60 N seems to be irrelevant.
How can the 4 forces be coplanar?

[image]

Comment: What? Use the horizontal dotted-line as x-axis, and use 60N as y-axis.

Comment: Why is the question downvoted?  Granted Anthony has some confusion and should show some effort, but it is a legitimate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting each known vector into an i or horizontal component and a j or vertical component.  If you first find the angle relative to positive x axis, which is typically 0 degrees, this can be down with sin and cos functions.  Sum all the known i components,  and separately all the known j components.  The result, R, is the net force of all known vectors.  P Newtons is simply, -R, which is the opposite of R.

Why must P N = - R ?
Consider thinking of it like this, R, the resultant of the 60N, 58N and 24N, forces, has the same effect as those three forces combined.  P N is one remaining force which balances out P N, and must be the opposite.  0 = -R + R = PN + R  For the object to be stationary, the net of all forces must sum to zero.  Any nonzero total net force, represents a nonzero acceleration, contradicting "stationary" mentioned in the question.

Comment: Why is P going to be the opposite of the resultant?

Comment: Feel free to edit, my answer, especially if you want to add diagrams.

Comment: Ahhh. STATIONARY. Missed that.

Comment: Surely, the force P N must have some vertical component. How can it be in the same plane as the known forces? In fact, its vertical component must be -60 since the other forces are in the horizontal plane.

Comment: First, off all these vectors are coplanar.  Assume for simplicity, they are in the xy plane, 
or i j plane.  The 60N is 0i + 60j, the 58 is mostly i and some negative j.  The 24N vector is mostly negative j and a bit negative i.   When you broke the known vectors down into i and j components with numbers what did you get?
If by vertical, you mean in the +j direction, maybe yes, maybe no.  Sometimes your intuition can lead you wrong.  Work the numbers, see how they all combine into a single vector with i and j.

Comment: I have been overthinking it. I was viewing the diagram as 3D and seeking some linear independence.

Coplanar => all the vectors are two dimensional. The entire diagram is 2D.

60N:  0i+60j
58N: 58cos22 i -58sin22 j
24N: -24cos68 i - 24sin68 j

Adding all these gives: 44.786 i + 16.020 j

Thus P is the negative of this (object is stationary)

P - -44.786 i -16.020 j

angle theta: tan theta = 16.020/33.786  => theta = 19.68 degrees